# \setbeamertemplate no effect in **infolines** outer theme

Tags: beamer, templates, presentations, themes

I am attempting to modify the section in header of my beamer. I use outer theme **infolines**. The command `\setbeamertemplate` has no effect in my case. Below is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot}{\hfill\thesection.\insertsectionhead}
\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}{\hfill\thesection.\insertsectionhead}
\begin{document}
    \section{title}
    \begin{frame}
        content...
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Why I cannot redefine the section in header or footer using command `\setbeamertemplate`?

Comment: `infolines` theme defines a header and  a footer that doesn't use `section in head/foot`.

Comment: @Ignasi so what is the **beamer element** used?

Comment: It's a `beamercolorbox` which calls `\insertsectionhead`. You can look for it. Search `beamerouterthemeinfolines.sty` file in your system or read it from [`CTAN`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/themes/outer/beamerouterthemeinfolines.sty)

Comment: @Ignasi so this means that we are not able to simply use **\setbeamertemplate** to redefine the section in header in **infolines** outer theme!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at file `beamerouterthemeinfolines.sty` where `infolines` outer theme is defined will see that infolines headline is defined with a `beamercolorbox` and not with a `section in head/foot` template. So if you want to change this theme it's better to take the original definition and change it according your taste. This is what I've done in following code. The original `\defbeamertemplate*{headline}` has been copied and converted to `\setbeamertemplate`, inserted between `\makeatother`+`\makeatletter` and changed to show `\thesection.\insertsectionhead`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,right]{section in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\thesection.\insertsectionhead\hspace*{2ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,left]{subsection in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex}\insertsubsectionhead
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \section{title}
    \subsection{subsection}
    \begin{frame}
        content...
    \end{frame}
    \section{new title}
    \subsection{another subsection}
    \begin{frame}
        content...
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]